# Changing preferences from Pyo to Pygame in Psychopy

Tags: audio, pygame, psychopy, pyo

I am trying to change the preferences of audiolib from Pyo to Pygame in Psychopy but it does not seem to work.

```
from psychopy import prefs, sound
prefs.general['audioLib'] = ['pygame']
.
.
.
sound1 = sound.Sound('name.wav')
sound1.play()
```

It keeps showing:

```
pyo version 0.8.0 (uses single precision)
```

The sound is alright but I want to use Pygame instead. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import sound after changing the preferences.

```py
# Set preferences first
from psychopy import prefs
prefs.general['audioLib'] = ['pygame']

# Now load the psychopy modules that you want, using the preferences above
from psychopy import sound
```